# Code written using visual studio C# 2005 does not work in visual studio c# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am currently working on the code which was written by people using visual studio C# 2005. After I run the code in visual studio C# 2010, this window pops up which says:

```
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue.the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.(Exception from HRESULT:0x8007000B)
***************Exception Text********

    System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.(Exception from `HRESULT:0x8007000B`)
    at PvNET.Pv.Initialize()
    at Camera TestApp.CamMeasurement.PVInitialize(Measurement Type measurement) in C:\...
    at Camera TestApp.PTCMeasurement,PTCMeasurement_Load(Object sender. EventArgs e) in 
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean flgnore Visible)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WindProc(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindProc(Message&m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(lntPtr hWind. lnt32msg. lntPtr wparam,lnt Ptr lntPtr lparam)
    **********Loaded Assemblies********
```

I don't know how to fix this. Could anyone tell me what causes this problem?

Comment: Probably trying to use a 64-bit library from a 32-bit program, or vice-versa.  It's impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Did you use the wizard to update the project?

Comment: Did you recompile the code? What is `PvNET`?

Comment: Or trying to load 4.0 assembly in 2.0 runtime....

Answer (score 3):

Pretty safe to assume that the original programmers didn't develop the code on a 64-bit operating system so used the default project settings.  And that a "CamMeasurement" is unmanaged code that only works in 32-bit mode.

Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Compile tab.  Change the Target platform setting from "AnyCPU" to "x86".

Answer (score 0):

Probably your program use 32 bits only native DLLs (not a problem on a 32 bits version of Windows or on a PC with only .NET 32 bits installed).

You have to go to the properties of your exe project and change in Build options the target CPU from AnyCPU to x86